# record data type as an input in postgres functions

Tags: postgresql-9.1

How to take record data type as an input in postgres functions ?

If we can not take record data type as an input in postgres functions then is there any other way to do it ?

suppose I want to save an employee details like emp_id,emp_name,emp_address,emp_contactno etc into employee table. I want to take these values from user input and also I want to do it for multiple employees in a single function call. We need to send the input to the function as a list of records of employee.

Comment: You need to add more information, and ideally some example of what you want to achieve.  In its present form the question is very hard to understand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I added more information about my query. could you please help me out.

Comment: It's still kind of hard to tell what you're after; maybe you should sketch out what you want as close as you can in PL/PgSQL (ie: show what you have so far) or even just pseudocode. So far it sounds like you might really want a writable CTE (wCTE) or a simple `UPDATE ... FROM` statement using a `VALUES` clause.

Comment: That kind of activity represents probably the bulk of all code written in database frontend applications, so that's just the way it is.  I suggest you do some reading about mechanisms like [DAO's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) or [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), this will show you how what I think your problem is are handled.